# How to search an specific button in a grid using webdriverIO

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, extjs, webdriver-io

I'm using an **[ExtJS](https://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/)** grid panel. This grid has more than 20 rows of info and I want to search in each row for an icon that represents **active mode**, using WebdriverIO as a test driver.

How can I search in each row till the test driver finds the first active icon? (**Note:** the grid I'm testing is hosted on *alegra.com*).

**Consider the following HTML print-screen:**

[image]

Comment: can you supply the html for what you are looking for? Give me an idea of what the row with the active icon would look like and I can probably help you out.

Comment: Salvador did you manage to fix this, or you still need help with it? Have a look at **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43686566/click-buttons-on-page-until-all-will-be-removed/43705794#43705794)** answer I gave for looping through `WebElement`s in WDIO. Also, which **alegra.com** view are you targeting? (`Contactos`, `Inventarios`, `Bancos`, etc.)

Comment: Hi men @iamdanchiv, still need help, i'm targeting right now to this module https://app.alegra.com/invoice , if you can see there is a grid with some rows, each row manage some action-icons, what i need is to find in that grid for example an active icon and then do click over it.

Comment: OK, I'll take a look once I get to a laptop. **:)**

Comment: Hey @iamdanchiv, what can we do with this test?

Comment: hi @iamdanchiv, im trying to get the grid using var grid = browser.elements('#someTableId > table > tbody > tr'); , but what i get in response is  http://take.ms/Dz36t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know exactly how to do it without knowing which locator you are using but if you first get a list of the rows and then filter them and grab the first match it should do what you are looking for.

```
public static get rows() { return browser.elements('#someTableId > table > tbody > tr'); }

public static getFirstMatch() {
    return this.rows.value.filter((row: WebdriverIO.Element) =>
        browser.elementIdElement(row.ELEMENT, 'someLocator').value)[0];
}
```

Comment: Hi men, this is a screenshot of the selectors---> http://take.ms/bqCwT if you can see there is the class .action-icons and below is the name of the button: [name="Ver detalle"]. This is just for one row, and there is more than one using the extjs selector.

Comment: if you want you can also open an test account on www.alegra.com

Comment: I dont know if the screenshot is enough?

Comment: Can you please explain me the getFirstMatch function, it is not clear for me

Comment: Yeah, the function is looking through all the rows in the table for an element that matches something you are looking for and returning the first match that it finds. That's what the index signature ([0]) at the end is for. In your case you want the row with the active icon so you would replace `someLocator` with whatever selector it is that identifies that icon.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i did it

```
var icon_type = 'delete';

it('Se elimina una factura', function(){        
        //rellenamos el array de elementos del grid
    var elements = browser.getAttribute('#gridInvoices #gridview-1047-table tbody tr .action-icons img:nth-child(7)','class');
        //Busca la primera coincidencia en el array con type
    var row_num = elements.indexOf(icon_type);

    if(row_num === -1){
        throw new Error('No se encontraron botones activos del tipo "Eliminar" en todo el grid' )
    }else{
        $$('#gridInvoices #gridview-1047-table tbody tr')[row_num].click('.action-icons [title="Eliminar"]');
        browser.click('=Sí')
        };  
});
```